# Why did Liz set her watch ahead 7 minutes?

Tags: plot-explanation, next

In the movie "Next", with Nicholas Cage, as Cris plans his escape from the Cliffhanger motel, he tells Liz to set her watch ahead by 7 minutes.

I figured that would come into play later in the story to misdirect the villains in some clever way.  But nothing about her watch, or her perception of what time it was, had any effect on the outcome.

So, what was the point of it?

Comment: I haven't seen it. Perhaps a premonition has the detail of what time it happens, according to her watch, but the timing means it's too late to save her, so he circumvents it by having that detail match, but adding the extra time needed to intervene.

Answer (score 2):

She's not setting her watch **ahead** 7 minutes, she's setting an **alarm or timer** for 7 minutes ahead.

Essentially, he's telling her to wait 7 minutes (until 9.17) and then do something so he can coordinate his timing with her actions.

Recall that just before starts his escape from the motel, he checks his watch and it's 9.17

[image]

Comment: Good screenshot.  You are right that it is 9:17 when he walks out of the motel room.  But, I disagree that Liz set an alarm.  Cris: "What time do you have?"  Liz: "9:10."  Cris: "Set your watch to 9:17."  Liz then twists the stem of her watch to change its time.  Cris then says: "Read this when I leave and wait exactly 45 seconds before you do what it says."  Since it is 9:17 once Cris gets out of the room, it definitely was not 9:17 while they were in the room talking.  A minor plot hole in a movie with many plot holes, but it is annoying. :)

Comment: You don''t see the change the time on her watch. Since they have to coordinate their actions she must be setting a timer/alarm.